# differentiation

Tags: laplace-transform

I wanna know how can I get Laplace transform by
differentiation of this unit step function

[image]

$$f(t)= u(t)-u(t-k)+2(u(t-k)-u(t-2k))+3(u(t-2k)-u(t-3k))+\ldots$$

I found that $$F(s) = \frac1s(1+e^{-ks}+(e^{-ks})^2+\ldots)=\frac1{s(1-e^{-ks})}$$

But by differentiation will be equal to zero :/

Any help and is there a specific name for this function

Comment: I think this is ( the function you show in the image  )  not a function at all, for some  $t$, $f(t )$ is not unique  !

Comment: "But by differentiation will be equal to zero" ?? "by differentiation" of what? "will be equal to zero" What will be equal to zero?

Comment: @Nizar "not unique" Which is not a problem to define the Laplace tansform.

Comment: @Did I  get it, thanks for the info!

Comment: I mean Laplace transforms of derivatives

Comment: Like getting f'(t) then applying.  L(f'(t))= SF(s)-f(0).    Or I am mistaken ?